# Why xterm doesn't have /dev/ptmx file opened?

Tags: terminal, xterm, terminal-emulator, open-files

`gnome-terminal` have the `/dev/ptmx` file opened:

[image]

But `xterm` doesn't have it opened:

[image]

I thought that each terminal emulator must have the `/dev/ptmx` file opened, so why xterm doesn't have it opened?

---

**Edit**: This is the output of `ls -ld "$(command -v xterm)"` (in response to  *Stéphane Chazelas*):

[image]

Comment: Is your `xterm` possibly setgid `utmp` like it used to be in the old days to be able to modify the utmp/wtmp database (IIRC)? That would explain why lsof can't see what files it has opened. Please show the output of `ls -ld "$(command -v xterm)"`

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas When I run `lsof` with root privileges (`sudo lsof`), `xterm` is shown to have the `/dev/ptmx` file opened. I edited my question to show the output of `ls -ld "$(command -v xterm)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Xterm has `/dev/ptmx` open, but you can't see it like this. Here's why.

Your `xterm` executable permissions have the `S_ISGID` (set-group-ID) bit set, and is group-owned `utmp`.

It's set up that way so that `xterm` can add an entry into `/var/run/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp` (exact paths may vary depending on your system) so your session shows in the output of `who` or `last`.

With those permissions, when `xterm` is executed, the process executing it will see its *effective* group id change to that of the `utmp` group (while the *read* group id will remain the same) which will give it permission to open the `utmp`/`wtmp` login records in write mode.

On Linux, as a security measure only `root` can list the open files of processes that have an effective user id different from the real user id, or effective group id different from the real group id. (you'll notice that for such processes, `/proc/<pid>fd` has `dr-x------ root root` permissions, compared to `dr-x------ you your-group` for other processes).

That's why `lsof`, when running as an ordinary user can't list the open files of that `xterm` process. You'd need to run `lsof` as `root`.

As to why it works for `gnome-terminals`, there are several possibilities:

- `gnome-terminal` doesn't add entries in the login records (that's the case on my system)
- `gnome-terminal` uses the `utempter` *helper* (which in that case is the one that is sgid `utmp`) to add the login records. That's what `xterm` and `konsole` do on my system.
- `gnome-terminal` resets the effective user id to the real user id (temporarily relinquishes the special `utmp` access) after it has updated the login records (which `xterm` doesn't do).

Answer (score 1):

That's the pseudo-terminal master device on **Linux**.  But xterm uses the POSIX function for opening the pseudo-terminal, which hides the details of opening the device.

There are different configurations for pseudo-terminals, but likely your system uses [this chunk](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/main.c#L2801):

```
#elif defined(HAVE_POSIX_OPENPT) && defined(HAVE_PTSNAME) && defined(HAVE_GRANTPT_PTY_ISATTY)
    if ((*pty = posix_openpt(O_RDWR)) >= 0) {
    char *name = ptsname(*pty);
    if (name != 0) {
        strcpy(ttydev, name);
        result = 0;
    }
}
```

VTE (the actual terminal emulator: "gnome-terminal" is a ***facade***) uses something similar (see [src/pty.cc](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/tree/src/pty.cc#n620)).

In practice it is not necessary to continue *using* the file-descriptor for the master device.  xterm runs as two processes, and *uses* that file descriptor in its "parent" process.  It discards the file descriptor for the master device in its ["child" process (see source)](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/main.c#L3923).

When you run xterm, the *child process* is the one which your shell talks to, e.g., if you run **`tty`** to see which terminal you are using (that is using the *slave* side of the pseudo-terminal, and the *master* side is closed because each process only needs to work with one side of the pseudo-terminal).

The *parent process* (which has `/dev/ptmx` open) manages the X window display.

Given all of that, I would expect to see `lsof` show xterm as having `/dev/ptmx` opened.  Except:

- in your screenshots, the message hints that you are not running as **root**, and if there is a permissions problem with `lsof` which prevents it from seeing all of the processes, then that could account for the missing information.
- your xterm is not actually running on the machine where you are running `lsof`, e.g., if you have ssh'd into the machine (and you happen to be seeing `gnome-terminal` running in a different session).

Comment: So `xterm` would still be sending data to the pseudo-terminal master (`/dev/ptmx`) and receiving data from it, but it is not `xterm` that opens the pseudo-terminal master (the kernel does?), and this is why the `/dev/ptmx` file is not shown opened for `xterm`. Am I correct?

Comment: sorry - I misread a slice - will update my answer.

Comment: AFAIK, `xterm` has only one process. The child process (that interacts with the slave side) that `xterm` spawns is the one that ends up **executing** the user's shell, so it's not _a `xterm` process that the shell talks to_.

Comment: xterm's "always" forked and used two processes.  When I debug it, there are two separate trace-files.  It does an `exec` with the child process after setting it up, but the initialization of the terminal is done while running as xterm.

Comment: Yes, but that second process is only running `xterm` for a few miliseconds. By the time the OP runs `lsof`, that process will be running the shell, so `lsof` will never show that process as a `xterm` process. Your statement about _the shell talking to that process_ is confusing. The shell **is** that process.

Comment: Sure - but as I pointed out, that process closes its connection to `/dev/ptmx`.

Comment: Sure, but that's beside the point (the OP is not complaining that his shell doesn't have a fd open on /dev/ptmx) and confusing the discussion.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey But if the `fd` of `/dev/ptmx` is closed, wouldn't that effectively close the connection to the master?